# Save the temporary file created by a task in a DAG and email it as an attachment in another task

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Am using Kubernetes executor https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html

My requirement is as below, There is a DAG that has two tasks.

- Bash Task A (BashOperator) , created a file at temp location, using python code
- Email Task B (EmailOperator), must access the above created file and send an email as an attachment

Apparently, In a Kubernetes Executor, each task instance is run in its own pod on a Kubernetes cluster. The worker pod then runs the task, reports the result, and terminates. Therefore after the worker pods shuts everything inside the pod is lost. Thus any file downloaded is lost.

**Note : No Storage mounted yet. Exploring easy options if any?.**

Would not like python code to send email too, instead want a separate task to email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are looking for the easiest option you can use the
  **Hostpath** to mount the files to **Node** and if you are running your container on a specific node pool POD will be able to get the
  files. **Note** : If the node goes down you files will be gone.
- If you want to share the file system between PODs you have to
  implement the **ReadWriteMany** **PVC**.
- If you are on any cloud provider you can use a **File system** like
  **AWS** to provide the **EFS**.
- You can also implement the **GlusterFS** or **Minio** to create the File
  system on K8s and use that as the mount option to PODs so those can
  access it share it.
- Could also leverage the s3 bucket option to upload the artifacts or
  files and new POD will download it first in temp location, email and
  terminate it self this way files will be saved at s3 and no clean up
  required at FS level or POD level.

Comment: Hi Harsh, Followed Option 5 from above. Instead of s3 used Azure Blob Storage.